# Invalid query, syntax to use near 'INET_ATON ('IP')'

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting this error:

> Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'INET_ATON('188.92.x.x')' at line 1

While trying to insert IP Address in database. The column type is:

> 'LastIP int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,'.

The function to execute the query is:

```
function onNewUser($ip, $hostname, $con)
{
    $query =    "INSERT INTO tableMachine (LastIP, LastHostName) VALUES ".
                "INET_ATON('".mysql_real_escape_string($ip, $con)."'), ".
                "'".mysql_real_escape_string($hostname, $con)."'";

    $result= mysql_query($query, $con);
    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());


    }
    }
```

I call this function with the parameters:

> $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
>
> $hostname = @gethostbyaddr($ip);
>
> onNewUser($ip, $hostname, $con);

What's wrong with it guys?

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/2864740 - it'll make the code safer, more robust, *and* easier to see what the *actual* SQL looks like.

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated in PHP 5.5. It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either `MySQLi_*` or `PDO`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this :

```
$query =    "INSERT INTO tableMachine (LastIP, LastHostName) VALUES (".
            "INET_ATON('".mysql_real_escape_string($ip, $con)."'), ".
            "'".mysql_real_escape_string($hostname, $con)."')";
```

I just add parenthesis for `VALUES(...)`

Also, as @Shamil said, the functions `mysql_*` are depricated. You should use `mysqli_*`[This link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php) should help you with the `mysqli_*` functions.

Answer (score 4):

your values list should be encapsulated inside of parenthesis if I am not mistaken